# Automatic Reference Counting (ARC). Can ARC handle free-ing a plain ole c-array?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

I am getting up to speed on using ARC for my iOS app development. Occasionally a plain ole c-array of plain old c-structs is all I need to get the job done. Prior to ARC I would just add `free()` to my `dealloc` method. With ARC there is nolonger any need for `dealloc`. Is there an ARC directive I can add to tell the compiler to handle free-ing my c-array(s)?

Per Tom's answer here is the dealloc method

```
// EIVertex
struct EIVertex {
    GLKVector3 p;
    GLKVector3 n;
    GLKVector3 barycentric;
    GLKVector2 st;
};

typedef struct EIVertex EIVertex;

// ivar declaration
EIVertex *_vertices;

// malloc an array of EIVertex
_vertices = (EIVertex *)malloc([_triangles count] * sizeof(EIVertex));

// Note lack of [super dealloc]
- (void)dealloc{

    // ARC will not handle mem. management for plain ole c arrays.
    free(_vertices);
}
```

Comment: Is `EIVertex` an Objective-C class? You should never use `sizeof` on an Objective-C class, because the size of a class can change at runtime. Maybe you want an array of pointers instead.

Comment: @newacct, EIVertex is a plain ole C struct. I just updated the code snippet to make that clearer. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still overload dealloc. The only thing is you can not explicitly call it. So write dealloc as you used to, but dont call `[super dealloc]` in it.

Comment: @Tom, just to clarify are you saying there is no ARC directive?

Comment: @Tom, for example if I simple declare my ivar as __strong would ARC then call `free()` for me?

Comment: No. You will have to call free in your dealloc on non-objective-c objects.